# Pass parameter to C# function in XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt

I have a XML and XSLT like this:

**XML**

```
<process id="1"> 
  <task id="task1">
  </task>
  <task id="task2">
  </task> 
  ...
</process>
```

**XSLT**

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">

    <![CDATA[
      public string GetStartTask(int ProcessID)
       {         
          return StartTask(ProcessID);
        }
    ]]>

</msxsl:script>

...
<xsl:if test="@id = user:GetStartTask(<xsl:value-of select="/../@id"/>)">
   ...
</xsl:if>
...
```

(`StartTask` is method that return string.)

In code above I try to pass `process id` to `GetStartTask` function by this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/../@id"/>
```

But this code is incorrect. I read many post but I don't find syntax for this issue.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you meant to write:

```
<xsl:if test="@id = user:GetStartTask(../@id)">
```

This is assuming you're in the context of `task` and you want to compare the value of the current task's `id`with the value returned by the `GetStartTask()` function with the parent process `id` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

If your current context is `<task>`, you should try

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@id" />
```

as an XSLT expression.